# jQuery Dialog - animate dialog to move from center to top-right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a form with the validation plugin setup. When the form is submitted and has errors, I am showing the error'ed fields in a dialog box (not modal).

The form could get really long really quick (business requirements keep adding fields) and I  made the errore'd fields in the dialog box clickable to scroll the window to the field in the from and highlight the fields. The dialog box is not dismissed at this point.

This dialog box is centered to start with and once the user starts clicking on the links, I need to move the dialog box out of the user's way and highlight (jQuery effect) the fields below.

To do this, I've come up with the following code and the dialog seems to animate to the top but not to the right. When I change 'right' to 'left' it works fine.

Below is the code and a jsbin to play with - http://jsbin.com/avigi3/4/

```
$('a.field').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').animate( {
        right : '0', /*left:'0' works fine here*/
        top : $(window).scrollTop()
    }, 'slow');
});
```

I debugged the jQuery.animate code and here are my notes:

1. jQuery.animate() 'starts' with the property's current value and gradually animates to the destination value as passed in. For ex: in the call, top starts with whatever the current top value of the dialog is and reduces to the scrollTop of the window (which is the visible top of the browser's viewport).
2. Now, here lies the problem. Even though the dialog is center-aligned, its 'right' property doesn't exist as jQuery-ui uses the 'left' property to center (absolutely position) the dialog. And since 'right' doesn't exist, the animation sequence for 'right' doesn't seem to work.

Did anyone face this issue? Any way I possibly could reset the 'right' position of the dialog so that it has 'some' value? Or can I configure jQuery dialog such that it animates when the position is changed programmatically and not manually by dragging.

Thanks,
-Syam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future readers, Shrikant's answer would be a quicker fix and specific to the call and it works fine. Just change width to use offsetWidth() to consider the paddings/margins.

I ended up following through the jQuery UI code to the end and have found a generic implementation. This is for jquery-ui 1.8.10.

Once it figures out where to move the dialog box by calculating {left:xxx, top:xxx}, jQuery-dialog uses the [Position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) utility to position and re-position the ui-dialog div. One of the options for Position is the 'using' function. If 'using' is defined, it triggers that function and passes in an object of {left:xxx, top:xxx}. If it is not defined, it just updates the css on ui-dialog. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
line number 9977 in jquery-ui version 1.8.10:
            if ( 'using' in options ) {
                options.using.call( elem, props );
            } else {
                curElem.css( props );
            }
```

You can override the 'using' property on the Position defaults, but since my usage is only for dialogs, I overwrote it on the dialog prototype:

```
$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
    position : {
        using : function(props) {
            $(this).animate( {
                left : props.left,
                top : props.top
            }, 'slow');
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Thanks,
-Syam

Comment: This answer is super useful - thanks for bringing it up. It would, however, be more terse to just pass in the props argument straight to .animate so you don't repeat yourself:

    $(this).animate(props);

Thanks again!

Comment: It changes the global behavior and is not quite applicable in practice. Look at this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849352/animating-jquery-dialog-to-different-position

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$('a.field').click(function(){
    dialog = $(this).closest('.ui-dialog')
    dialog.animate( {
        left: document.width - dialog.width(), // or you might want to use .outerWidth()
        top: $(window).scrollTop()
    }, 'slow');
});
```