# Animating jQuery dialog to different position

Tags: jquery

I am designing a webpage where I have got 6 dialog boxes in a grid layout. Each dialog box has a button. I want it to work this way: when user clicks on the button, the dialog box should get expand and the other boxes should move to the right side with proper alignment and shrink the box sizes. I am stuck in animating the boxes that are suppose to move to the right. Please help!

jQuery function:

```
$("#searchButton").click(function () { 
    $("#dialog1").animate({"right": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    $("#dialog3").dialogr({position: [800,400]},{duration:1500});
})
```

In the above code, the contents of dialog1 move to the right instead of box itself, dialog3 moves to the specified position without animation.
Please hemp me animate these boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to animate the jQuery UI widgets instead of the original elements:

```
$("#searchButton").click(function() { 
    $("#dialog1").dialog("widget").animate({
        right: "+=50px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#dialog3").dialog("widget").animate({
        left: "800px",
        top: "400px"
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, that dint work. When saying "widget", do you mean I need to mention the widget name, i.e. dialogr? I tried both, widget and dialogr, it dint work as expected. I am new to jQuery.

Comment: @rahul, sorry, I did not know of [dialogr()](http://carvalhar.com/componente/jQueryDialogr/index.html) before now, and I assumed it was a typo. I was referring to the [widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-widget) method of jQuery UI dialogs. In your case, you need to call `dialogr()` instead of `dialog()`. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thats ok Frederic. I tried your code, but I am sorry, it still doesnt work. The only change that I can see now is the contents of dialog3 are getting moved bot not the box itself.

Comment: @rahul, strange, `dialogr("widget")` should return the top-level element. Maybe `dialogr()` diverges from jQuery UI in this aspect. Out of curiosity, can you check that `$("#dialog3").dialogr("widget")` indeed returns the same element as `$("#dialog3")`?

Comment: How do I check that?
I tried these 2 lines of code:
      $("#dialog3").animate({left: "200px", top: "200px"},1500);    
      $("#dialog3").dialogr("widget").animate({left: "200px", top: "200px"},1500);   

There is no difference, these 2 lines yield the same thing.

Comment: @rahul, `alert($("#dialog3").dialogr("widget").attr("id") == "dialog3");`. If it says `true`, `dialogr()` does not behave like jQuery UI's `dialog()`, my answer is invalid, and I don't know if what you want to achieve is possible...

Comment: It says true. Let me try the same thing with dialog instead of dialogr, then I will get back to you. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: @rahul, another idea: apparently, the widget element still exposes the `ui-dialog` class. Does the code work as expected if you replace `.dialogr("widget")` with `.closest(".ui-dialog")`?

Comment: Hey, I just replaced the dialogr with dialog in the code and it works perfect! Anyways, I am not compelled to use dialogr.
I think I got what I was looking for!  

    $("#dialog1").dialog("widget").animate({left: "+=50px"}, "fast");  
    $("#dialog3").dialog("widget").animate({left: "200px", top: "200px"},1500);
    $("#dialog3").dialog("widget").animate({left: "200px", top: "200px"},1500);

This code makes the boxes move in a weird manner, but I got the logic now.
Bro, I will buy you a beer when you come to NYC!

Comment: @rahul, thanks for the beer :) I was surprised `dialogr()` behaved differently, but it's probably based on an older version of jQuery UI that implemented `dialog("widget")` that way, because I fail to understand why they would have to break that method in order to add buttons to the title bar. However, if you want to keep those buttons (and `dialogr()`), you can try the `closest()` approach detailed above. Cheers :)

Comment: I replaced dialog("widget") with .closest(".ui-dialog"). It worked in the similar way. Thanks a lot man. Cheers! :)

Comment: can you tell me how to move the boxes in diagonal fashion and not like horizontal/vertical fashion?

Comment: @rahul, since that's another topic, I'd suggest you ask that in another question (with more details on the motion you're looking for and, if at all possible, the relevant parts of your code :)